# importing an obj-c library to swift results in parse issues

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to import [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio) to my Swift project. As my project is written in Swift, I use the bridging header to import it. I therefore copied [this](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/tree/master/EZAudio) folder to my project, and added each file individually to the bridging header file. For example:

```
#import "EZAudioPlayer.h"
```

When I try to compile I get parse issues.

I have checked that Xcode sees the bridging header file by going to Build Settings and checking the path to this file is correct under the Swift Compiler section.

Some screenshots:

[image: Parse Issues]

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: Are you using Carthage or Cocoapods, or are you importing it directly?

Comment: Just dragged and dropped the folder to Xcode. Target membership was set to my project. I'm also pretty sure it copied the files correctly, because when I remove them Xcode complains that the files are not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly checked the "AZAudio.h" and I can say that the problem is the circle reference present in all Objective-C files.

Writing `#import "EZAudioPlayer.h"` will import "AZAudio.h", that inside has the original "EZAudioPlayer.h", creating a circular header reference that Swift doesn't like.

You have two potential solutions here:

- Using Cocoapods or Carthage
- Editing all the headers to avoid circular references, using the `@class` directive in every Header(.h) file and moving the `#import` macro to the Implementation file (.m).

Comment: Have you use carthage for EZAudio? I've tried but with no succes